# How to send text (or URL) AND image with AirDrop at the same time

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, share, airdrop

I am trying to share a text (or an URL) and an image with AirDrop and it seems it sends only the image. It works fine with other sharing activities (Facebook, Twitter, Mail, Message etc.). Is it possible to share two items with AirDrop?
Here is how I use the UIActivityViewController:

```
 UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[self.activityItem, self.attachedImage] applicationActivities:nil];
```

self.attachedImage is an UIImage and self.activityItem is a subclass of UIActivityItemProvider which returns different text for different activity types in delegate method

```
- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

EDIT:

I also tried without subclassing UIActivityItemProvider and passed directly some text. Didn't work.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"some text", self.attachedImage] applicationActivities:nil];
```

As a note, it works if I want to share multiple texts OR multiple images (UIImage):

```
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"text 1", @"text 2"] applicationActivities:nil];

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[attachedImage1, attachedImage2] applicationActivities:nil];
```

Comment: Use string don,t use subclass of UIActivity indicator...

Comment: @C_X Tried already, doesn't work

Comment: what did you tried... update code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted the same question on Apple Dev Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/937697#937697

Got this answer:

> Currently not possible. AirDrop only lets you send sets of single
>   items. If you are trying to send it to an instance of your own app on
>   the other side, you could instead create a fileformat (a
>   bundle/package would probably be suitable here) and embed all the
>   different types with the file. Then on the receiving side you can
>   extract the different types out of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
NSString *text= @"text to share";
CustomActivityItemProvider *textToShare = [[CustomActivityItemProvider alloc]
                                           initWithStandardText:text];

NSArray *activityItems = @[textToShare,self.attachedImage];
```

Use `activityItems` array in activity view controller.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing. I have a subclass of UIActivityItemProvider which returns a text. Then I pass the item to the UIActivityViewController in initWithActivityItems:applicationActivities: along with the image.